# CSS won't load on Firefox, works on Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have my portfolio running on [4ormat](http://4ormat.com). My site [is here](http://www.retouchandrestore.com).

I added a custom CSS so you can hover over each image and have it show a before/after. So a rollover effect essentially.

This is the custom CSS I added:

```
#menu .item.selected a{ background: #444; }

::-moz-selection{ background: #A5A29F; color:#fff; text-shadow: none; }
::selection { background:#A5A29F; color:#fff; text-shadow: none; }
.rollover a{
   display: block;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   margin: auto auto auto auto;
   cursor: pointer;
   outline: transparent solid 0px;
} 


#example a{
    height: 550px;
    width: 450px;  
    background: url('www.example.com')
    no-repeat right top;
}
#example a:hover,
#example a:active{
   background-position: 0 0; 
}
```

And I uploaded every image as a custom HTML text and used this as the code -

```
<div class="text_content">
     <div class="rollover" id="gold">
        <a href="http://a1.format-assets.com/image/private/s--K-oDqQbt--    /c_fill,g_center,h_550/a_auto,fl_keep_iptc.progressive,q_95/161188-8364422-gold.jpg">

        </a>
        </div>
PHOTO BY STEFAN B.
</div>
```

I’m really lost as to why it works flawlessly on Chrome and Safari and doesn’t seem to work on Firefox. I know it is possible because [this website](http://www.sarahcrump.com/retouching) is using pretty much the same codes as me and it works on FireFox.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers, IE, Safari, Opera etc?

Comment: You're going to have to explain to us what not "working flawlessly" is supposed to mean.  What part is broken?  Don't expect us to open your code in different browsers and see the same problems as you.

Comment: @Timmah It works in Safari, I haven't checked the other ones. If it doesn't work in IE or Opera that's fine as long as I can get it to work in Firefox.

Comment: @Sparky In Chrome & Safari, everything loads and the hover effects work. In Firefox the photos won't load. You can still navigate the site but you can only see the photo caption with a link attached to it but it won't load the actual photo.

Comment: Look at your Firefox console.  There are all kinds of `Unknown property - Declaration dropped` errors and warnings in the CSS tab.

Comment: @JakeGould, Oh, I'm sure it was obvious... was just trying to get the OP to do that.  +1 from me on your answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your CSS in `custom_stylesheet.css` [over here](http://www.retouchandrestore.com/custom_stylesheet.css). The issue is in this chunk of CSS code:

```
/*This is for you Matt*/
#giveIDnamehere a{
    height: 550px;
    width: ; /*Set half the image width here*/ 
    background: url('); /*Link to image here*/
    no-repeat right top;
}
#models a:hover,
#models a:active{
   background-position: 0 0; 
}
/**/
```

Note the `background: url(');` is simply set to one single quote `'` when it should be `''`.

```
/*This is for you Matt*/
#giveIDnamehere a{
    height: 550px;
    width: ; /*Set half the image width here*/ 
    background: url(''); /*Link to image here*/
    no-repeat right top;
}
#models a:hover,
#models a:active{
   background-position: 0 0; 
}
/**/
```

Once I adjusted that in a desktop copy I made of the HTML & CSS for debugging this everything seems to work as expected in FireFox 29 on Mac OS X 10.9.3:

[image]

Also—as others have noted—there is definitely a lot to clean up here. But the specific error was quite glaringly obvious once the CSS was loaded into a text editor with context coloring. Look at the following screenshot from BBEdit to see what I mean. Heck, look at the context coloring in my sample of the error above.

[image]

Also, here is your CSS & HTML nicely formatted in BBEdit via it’s internal code formatting tools on Pastebin:

- [stylesheet.css](http://pastebin.com/EFhpMBKj)
- [custom_stylesheet.css](http://pastebin.com/jF58cGgZ)
- [tidy_index.html](http://pastebin.com/LdjjuMtM)

Cleaning up code & making it nicely formatted helps clear up issues like this pretty quickly.

Comment: Wow I can't believe that was the problem. I didn't realize that was the problem at all. Thank you, really appreciate it.

Comment: The line that follows that with `no repeat` is also incorrect, and `width` should have a value.

Comment: Thanks guys, will definitely try and learn how to clean things up better. Glad this main issue got resolved though. Really appreciate the help.

Comment: @JakeGould This is great, thanks a lot. Will definitely look those over and keep them in case I run into anymore issues. Thanks for taking the time to do that.